# Facebook app links (deep linking) not working on android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I have the following tags in my phonegap app index.html file:

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="myApp://test.myapp.me/">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="myapp.market.test">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="TestApp">
```

In Facebook url debug tool i see the same tags under "app links android" in the developer tools.

My app package name is: "myapp.market.test"

But if someone click on a shared link on Facebook app, for example: "myapp.me/index.html?id=something" the link opens in the mobile browser instead of opening my app.

As i understand the only meta tag here that responsible for the app to open is "al:android:package".

Am i doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add this line in your Manifest

```
<data android:scheme="myApp"/>
```

Don't forget this in "intent-filter" tag of Activity you want to open

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
```